# MongoEngine - Load all referenced documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

Lets say I have two collections in my mongodb, `product` and `color` defined as

```
class Color(Extended):
    name = StringField()

class Product(Extended):
    name = StringField()
    colors = ListField(ReferenceField(Color, dbref=True))
```

And that I have a document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61b1080d361ca805e35bafa5"),
    "_cls" : "Product",
    "name" : "name",
    "colors" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "color",
            "$id" : ObjectId("61b108e418a1aacb47c3a15f")
        }
    ]
}
```

Usually, I make queries like

```
Product.objects.get(id=_id).to_json()
```

But that only returns

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61b1080d361ca805e35bafa5"),
    "_cls" : "Product",
    "name" : "name",
    "colors" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "color",
            "$id" : ObjectId("61b108e418a1aacb47c3a15f")
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I fetch the referenced documents **automatically**?

Comment: This feels like python.

Comment: It seems you have two possibilities - 1.) use $lookup in an aggregation pipeline, or 2.) identify a deep hydrate method of `mongoengine`.  NodeJS Mongoose has a similar concept called `Populate()` - see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-populate-method/

Comment: By the way, it is advisable to ensure the PyMongo driver used by mongoengine is compatible with the version of MongoDB you are using.  Detecting the driver version might not be a trivial exercise.